# Getting error [UIImage length]: unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, runtime-error, unrecognized-selector

I got this error

> 2014-05-08 11:36:11.781 LtrRainOptic[1176:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7af55c0'

```
 -(void)letterfall
{
   letterView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   image4 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, -80, 200, 200)];
   image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[sprtL objectAtIndex:0]];
   [letterView addSubview:image4];
   self->falling=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self    selector:@selector(letterPosition) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)setImagesInArray
{
    if (numLtr == 1)
{
       //if (r == 1) {   [self filltheLetterArray];}
        image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[oneletter objectAtIndex:r]];
       r++;
}

}

-(void)filltheLetterArray
{
   fillrequried = [self requiredArray];
   int rand;
    if (numLtr == 1)
   {
       rand = (0 + arc4random()%(1));
      [oneletter replaceObjectAtIndex:rand withObject:[sprtL objectAtIndex:sliderindex]];
      if (rand == 1) {    [oneletter replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[sprtL objectAtIndex:[self randomImage]]];}
      else           {    [oneletter replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[sprtL objectAtIndex:[self randomImage]]];}
}
    [self letterfall];
}


-(void)letterPosition
{
    if (numLtr == 1)
    {
        image4.frame = CGRectMake(image4.frame.origin.x, image4.frame.origin.y + 2, image4.frame.size.width, image4.frame.size.height);
    }
    if (image4.frame.origin.y >= 690) 
    {  
        [falling invalidate];
        falling = nil;
        [self filltheLetterArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line you are getting this error. The error says that you are sending the [UIImage length] to a selector which doesn't accept length.

Comment: You could also use the xCode debugger with a breakpoint on the line which trigger the error and check the type of the pointer and its value by writing `po myPointer` (with my pointer the name of the incriminated variable) on the xCode consol.

Comment: It seems like in some places where you initialize the image [UIImage imageWithName:], you are passing it image itself instead of string.

Comment: Like @insane-36 said, check the parameter given to `imageNamed` method and its returned value.

Comment: how can i generate an .app file i have an apple id and it's paid for 1 year also please if any one knows how reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's problem in your `filltheLetterArray` method, you're replacing objects in `oneletter` array, you're storing images (`UIImages` from `randomImage` method)directly into it, and this method crashing the app, `setImagesInArray`, this line `image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[oneletter objectAtIndex:r]];` as you're assigning image file name (as `NSString`) but actually its containing `UIImage` objects.